# Azure cloud service: Can't change instances size to D series AggregateException

Tags: azure, deployment

I am trying to change the vmsize in my cloud service from Small to Standard_D2_V2, the first problem encountered is that this size is not available in the UI properties of my azure Role. The V2 instance sizes are not visible in the VM size dropdown list. Anyway, I decided to set up the Standard_D2 size but got the following error when trying to deploy using the cloud service through the CD build definition (tfs):

Exception Message: Invalid enum value 'Standard_D2' cannot be deserialized into type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.AzureManagement.v1_7.InstanceSize'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute. (type SerializationException)

Comment: Are you using the latest Azure SDK?

Comment: I tried with SDK 2.6 and 2.8, 2.9 didn't worked because the Hosted Controller doesn't support it yet